# How to get the tweet id for the tweet generated using tweepy library's update_status method

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

To post a new tweet via tweepy, I've used the below code

```
#Twitter credentials - Augrav
access_token = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'access_token')
access_token_secret = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'access_token_secret')
consumer_key = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'consumer_key')
consumer_secret = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'consumer_secret')
account_id = config.get('twitter_credentials', 'account_id')

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = API(auth)
msg = "Howdy howdy"
api.update_status(status=msg)
```

How to get this newly generated tweet id ?

There's no info about this in the official tweepy docs.
Ref: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more trivial than you would probably want to believe.

From the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html#API.update_status) you can see that the `update_status` method returns a `status` object. As do most methods in the `API`. This `status` object essentially contains all the information about that tweet.

```
# after establishing a connection
In [15]: msg = "Tweeting from tweepy"

# retain the object returned
In [16]: tweet = api.update_status(status=msg)

# the id (and practically any attribute, print a tweet to view them!)
# can be easily accessed via
In [17]: tweet.id_str
Out[17]: u'646306396464656384'
```